# Calculating infinitesimally small volume of a sphere in velocity space

Tags: thermodynamics, velocity, volume

[This link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/maxspe.html) (at the end of the page) is deriving the formula to calculate an infinitesimally small volume $dV$ on the surface of a sphere with radius $v$ in velocity space. It states that $dV = dv_xdv_zdv_z$. I have drawn this small volume piece in velocity space myself and deduced the following
[image]

So I have deduced that $dV = \sin(\theta) \cdot v \cdot d\phi \cdot v \cdot d\theta \cdot dv$. This is also what the link states. However, I really can't see how this is the same as $dV = dv_xdv_zdv_z$. According to my drawing, I have deduced that
$$dv_z = \sin(\theta)\cdot v\cdot d\phi\cdot \sin(\phi)$$
$$dv_x = \sin(\theta)\cdot v\cdot d\phi\cdot \cos(\phi)$$
$$dv_y = \sin(\theta) \cdot v \cdot d\theta$$
But I can't equate them to make $dV = \sin(\theta) \cdot v \cdot d\phi \cdot v \cdot d\theta \cdot dv$.

Comment: you should obtain  the metric  $G$ for a sphere. if you have the metric your volume element is: $dV=\sqrt{|\det{G}|}\,dv\,d\Phi\,d\theta$

Comment: @Eli Sorry I don't know what you mean. Isn't it possible to deduce it using my derived formulas?

Comment: this is how you can calculate the $dV$ mathematically, but if you don't understand it you have to use your geometrical construct,sorry i can't help you with this